# NPM-Request handle on data stop flowing/streaming

Tags: node.js, express, stream, request, npm-request

I'm piping a CCTV stream using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), and serve it using Express. 
Sometimes there is problem with network connection in the middle of streaming, that cause in the client picture freeze on the last chunked data.

I need to catch this event so I can manipulate on the client by serve some-error image file. I tried `exit`, `close`, `finish`, `stop` events but none success.
So far I didn't found similar problem on [request's Issues](https://github.com/request/request/issues) or on other SO questions.

Comment: How would you start to reproduce the problem based on this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for being late,

I figure out that passing `timeout` [option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback) can catch network disconnection and trigger `error` event. It printed as `Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT.`

This is quite enough for my needs.